# Generating mask array for existence of each element of a list in another list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

Do you think there is a faster way to do it?
Or more efficient way in terms of both runtime and memory.

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list2 = ['b', 'c']
>>> mask_array = [True if x in list2 else False for x in list1]
>>> mask_array
[False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: `x in list2` is linear time, you will get better performance by converting `list2` to `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`, you can obtain the mask with [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) for a more performant approach:

```
>>> list1=['a','b','c','d']
>>> list2=['b','c']

>>> np.isin(list1, list2)
>>> array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

---

Timings,

```
a = np.random.randint(0,200_000, 100_000)
b = np.random.randint(0,10_000, 10_000)

%timeit np.isin(a,b)
# 8.78 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
set2 = set(b)
mask_array = [x in set2 for x in a]
# 15.9 ms ± 606 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I measured execution times of your and my solution, and numpy seems to perform slower. Do you know why? Isn't it weird?

Comment: Not weird @RiccardoBucco The list approach is just `O(n)`, we have a single scan over the list with a `O(1)` lookup, shoudn't be slow. We're talking a simple operation here. Getting slightly different timings than yours though

Comment: You might have better timings because you are working with numpy arrays instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['b', 'c']

set2 = set(list2)
mask_array = [x in set2 for x in list1]
```

The lookup operation for sets costs O(1) on average, which is much less than lookup in a list O(n).

Here you can see the difference, which is huge:

```
from time import time
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(7)

list1 = [random.randrange(1000000) for i in range(100000)]
list2 = [random.randrange(1000000) for i in range(100000)]

start = time()
mask_array = [True if x in list2 else False for x in list1]
stop = time()
print(stop - start) # 93.71739292144775

start = time()
set2 = set(list2)
mask_array = [True if x in set2 else False for x in list1]
stop = time()
print(stop - start) # 0.022114992141723633

start = time()
mask_array = np.isin(list1, list2)
stop = time()
print(stop - start) # 0.03964031219482422
```

90 seconds vs <1 second!!

In this case you can see that my solution is even faster than the `np.isin` solution.

Comment: but plz also replace the `True if something else False` with just `something`, it hurts :P

Comment: `True if x in set2 else False`, is the same as  `x in set2`